# I have issue with React forms when I try to post form with file type input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-forms

*Hello everyone,
When I try to post form with file type input, my request stuck pending and not add to my database. Can someone help ?

*

*this is my upload method.*

```
const addBook =  ( name, author, category, about, pdf, image) => {
        const book = { 
             name,
             author, 
             category, 
             about, 
             pdf, 
             image
        };
        axios.post('http://localhost:3004/book', book)
             .then(response => {  
                 books.push(book);
                 setBooks(books);  
                });
    }
```

*this is my Addbook React function component*

```
   const { addBook } = useContext(BookContext);


   const [newBook, setNewBook] = useState({
       name:"" , author:"", category:"", about:"", pdf:"", image:""
   })

   const {name, author, category, about, pdf, image} = newBook;

   const onInputChange = (e) => {
       setNewBook({...newBook, [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
   }

   const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        addBook(name, author, category, about, pdf, image);
   }
    return ( 
        <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
       
       <Form.Group>
                <Form.Control
                    type ="Text"
                    placeholder="Name *"
                    name="name"
                    value={name}
                    onChange={e => onInputChange(e)}
                    required
                />
            </Form.Group>

            <Form.Group>
                <Form.Control
                    type ="Text"
                    placeholder="author *"
                    name="author"
                    value={author}
                    onChange={e => onInputChange(e)}
                    required
                />
            </Form.Group>

            <Form.Group>
                <Form.Control
                    as ="textarea"
                    placeholder="category *"
                    name="category"
                    value={category}
                    onChange={e => onInputChange(e)}
                    rows={3}
                />
            </Form.Group>
            
            <Form.Group>
                <Form.Control
                    type ="Text"
                    placeholder="about *"
                    name="about"
                    value={about}
                    onChange={e => onInputChange(e)}
                />
            </Form.Group>         

            <Form.Group>
                <Form.Control
                    type ="text"
                    placeholder="image *"
                    name="image"
                    value={image}
                    onChange={e => onInputChange(e)}
                />
            </Form.Group>
           
            <Form.Group>                        
            <Form.Control
                    type ="file"
                    placeholder="pdf"
                    name="pdf"
                    value={pdf}
                    onChange={e => onInputChange(e)}
                />
                              
            </Form.Group>

           

            <Button variant="success" type="submit" >
                 Add new Book
            </Button>

        </Form>
            
        )
}

export default AddBook;
```

Can you please answer my problem because, I dont have time so much for this project deadline.
thank you for your helping.

- Have nice coding everyone... *

Answer (score 0):

Mention Content Type in headers like this

```
axios.post('http://localhost:3004/book', book,{{headers:{'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}})
    .then(response => {  
        books.push(book);
        setBooks(books);  
     });
```